# So I was out drinking last night...how do I remove a tattoo?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Geralt got into a bit of fun with the Blue Stripes last night. After getting rip-roaringly drunk, the Witcher thought it might be good to see if it was possible to float across the river on the bums of four prostitutes. It wasn't. The Witcher woke without equipment and a new tattoo on his neck.

The equipment was easy to recover, as Ves had our back, but now Geralt has a nude woman brandishing a sword on his neck. It sorta clashes with the whole "monster slayer" vibe I'm going for. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: PCs get drunk too!

Comment: @Andrew The OP did state that it *didn't* work... Guess I won't be trying to myself then.

Comment: @deceze: If you want to get technical, I used the subjunctive!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Talk to Triss about it. She'll tell you that she can remove it, with the help of a few ingredients:

- Green Mold
- White Myrtle Petals
- Wolf's Aloe

White Myrtle is very common, so you probably already have some. Wolf's Aloe and Green Mold can both be bought from Anezka (the herbalist on the outskirts of town) for 125 orens apiece.

Comment: What if Triss has already been kidnapped?

Comment: @Raven I suspect you're out of luck until you can talk to her again, though I'm not that far in the story yet.

Comment: Triss kidnapped?  We need to get a `spoiler` tag for comments!

Comment: @Iszi But really, any of us that have played the game for all of about 15 seconds should know that at least one if not all of Geralts female interests have the possibility... sooooo SURPRISE!

Comment: @JeffLangemeier - Some of us haven't played the game at all yet.  I'm still working through the first one.

Comment: @Iszi - I suppose I assumed that since from essentially the opening scene of the first game we find that all of Geralt's female companions are expendible in some manner, we shouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [sjohnston's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/so-i-was-out-drinking-last-night-how-do-i-remove-a-tattoo/22867#22867):

You can remove tattoo in Chapter 2 , talk to Sìla. There is the same dialog option for removing the tattoo, and you still need those same ingredients, which can also be bought in Chapter 2.

Comment: Sìla looks to be unavailable if you don't pick Roche's path. I wonder if Philippa (her counterpart sorceress, as I understand it) occupies a similar niche.