# I lost all my stuff after a night of hard drinking... Can I get it back?

Tags: the-witcher-2

There I am, woken up by the townsfolk after a night I cannot remember completely.

I lost all my stuff now, Triss is waiting for me at the Kayran's lair, and I have no armor and no blade.

Should I roll back to an earlier save or can I get my stuff back somehow?

Comment: How could I guess this was a "the witcher 2" question?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm : Check out the tags.

Comment: I get the feeling you all play this game only to write headlines like this.

Comment: I guessed it was from "the witcher 2" while it was one of those ads on the right hand side, before coming to this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your stuff back. When you wake up, you should be next to Rudy, who will tell you that you don't want to remember what happened last night. Bribe or intimidate him anyways and he'll tell you that he's not the one to ask, but that the madame Marlot should know. Find her in the basement of the inn(the building where the notice board is located). When you head down the stairs to the basement, and go into the more open area(where there are/were people fighting), you'll notice a door by the corner. This leads into another hallway. When you go through that door, there's another door to the right leading into an elegant bedroom. This is madame Marlot's room.

I believe she also requires to be bribed. After you've done that, she'll tell you that you should go speak and apologize to Ves. Visit Ves in Roche's house(the place where you got drunk to begin with) and she'll tell you the full details of your night and mention that your stuff can be found in the chest by the window.

It seems this is the only path through the quest; you must bribe or intimidate Rudy to get your quest directives. You can't skip straight to Ves and get your stuff back since she has the key and you need to follow the quest to get the dialogue option.  Rudy's the guy with the fishing rod right by where you woke up.

As of Patch 1.2, the bribe option always remains open even after bribe failure, fixing the bug where people could not progress after failure on both intimidation and bribery.

Comment: You may also want to investigate [tattoo removal](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/so-i-was-out-drinking-last-night-how-do-i-remove-a-tattoo).

Comment: OMG who did that to my neck??!!

Comment: Yeah, that guy I tried to bribe found I could give him more, and when I tried again there is no bribe option. Is the Madame Marlot path still open? And where do I find her, I'm assuming near the brothel?

Comment: @Bora I'll have to do more testing on the different paths, but I kinda assumed that if everything else fails, you can simply head straight to Ves, ask what happened and grab your stuff. I also edited with a description of Madame Marlot's location.

Comment: @Mana I asked Ves directly, there was no relevant conversation option available. I also checked the chests in the room, but couldn't find my stuff.

Comment: Hm, okay. Definitely need to test this then. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this extensively. If you fail to bribe Rudy at the river bank, you are done for good: 1. There won't be any more conversation, and, 2. Since he won't talk to you, you won't be able to visit Madame Marlot, and Ves behaves completely oblivious to the happenings. All in all, you will lose your stuff for good. I went to a previous save, and went on from there. Now I am after the Kayran and I will try skipping this part of story if I can.

Comment: @Bora mm, that's weird, because I also tested this extensively and even if you fail the bribe [there's still an intimidation option open with him, always](http://i.imgur.com/Y7mig.jpg).

Comment: That's right. I remember also, that I failed the intimidation.

Comment: @Bora Edited to note that possibility. Reloading to your last save's your only hope, then, I guess.

Comment: @Bora According to the [Patch 1.2 notes](http://ve3d.ign.com/articles/news/60686/The-Witcher-2-1-2-Patch-Details), this progress break has now been fixed. I'm not sure exactly how.