# Can I get pregnant?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

In most Harvest Moon games where you could get married, after a while your wife would get pregnant and have a baby (or two). Since your wife was an NPC it usually had little impact on gameplay.

In Harvest Moon: A New Begining I picked a female character and just noticed that there are, in fact, male dating options. I'm wondering if the same "settle down and have kids" things plays out, and if so, what affects that has on gameplay (pregnancy is not conducive to large amounts of farming labor). Can my character get pregnant? If so, does that affect me at all or do I just take a day off to have the kid (which is how I believe past HM games handled this)?

Comment: Clearly, the male gets pregnant.

Comment: @Tacroy: It wouldn't surprise me if that happens...

Comment: Continuing in the grand tradition of unfortunate Harvest Moon question titles, are we?

Comment: Psh, a day off to have a kid?  C'mon, you can have the baby in the fields.  That corn won't farm itself, y'know?

Comment: I didn't expect you all to be so judgmental of my life choices

Comment: @Yawus I think [tag:the-witcher-2] still has one of the most amusing question titles around, here. [So I was out drinking last night... how do I remove a tattoo?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22862/6274)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can.  [This website explains:](http://fogu.com/hm11/marriage/raising-your-child.php)

You'll have to get the blueprint for the Child's bed from Rebecca for 3200 G.  The blueprint requires 10 Black Lumber, 5 Suffolk Wool, 10 Alpaca Wool and 1 Pink Diamond.

After marriage, the pregnancy event will trigger in 30 days.  If you don't have the child's bed, then the event will be postponed until you have one.

The pregnancy lasts 60 days, and there is **no gameplay difference**.

The baby will stay in its bed not moving for 62 days, then he/she will start the crawling cutscene.  After the cutscene, the baby will return to it's bed.  You can now talk to the baby, but you can't give it gifts.

After 62 more days, the baby will develop into a child, he/she will move about the farm and you can now give him/her gifts.

After at least 30 days and 60,000 FP, the Harvest Goddess will come to you house and give your child a piece of Candy.  This will turn them into a teenager for 30 days, not a full 31-day season.  After 30 days, the candy will wear off and they will revert back into a child.  Your teenager can only forage, same as your spouse, on Fridays and Saturdays if the weather is sunny.

If you want another piece of Candy, give Alice the Harvest Sprite some Royal Jelly.  The mountain honey bee is the only bee that can produce the Royal Jelly needed.

Comment: So, does the child ever grow into an adult?

Comment: @Iszi No, they'll be in a continuous loop from child to teenager.

Comment: That is the weirdest child rearing cycle I have ever seen.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I know, normally it's the other way around - if you give teenagers candy, they revert back to children :)

Comment: I wonder if the child ever realizes you've basically giving him candy in exchange for otherwise unpaid labor

Comment: @BenBrocka I'm getting unpaid labor if you don't click that check! :P